# НЕ или НИ с союзом "чтобы"

Tags: орфография, не-или-ни

**Что бы я не сделал, чтобы пошел дождь!**

Какую частицу правильно использовать в предложении?
На мой взгляд, правильно "не", потому что у придаточного предложения нет уступительного значения. Однако в справочниках похожих примеров нет.
Сомнения подогреваются невозможностью изменить погоду, в отличие от примера
("На какие только ухищрения не пускается человек, чтобы не пропасть".).

Answer (score 1):

**Что бы я не сделал, чтобы пошел дождь!**

Здесь нет уступительного значения, это риторический вопрос.

Похожий вариант: **Что бы я не сделал, чтобы всё было по-прежнему!**

Отметим, однако, что в таких предложениях повтор ***что бы/чтобы*** можно счесть за **стилистическую неточность.**

Answer (score 0):

Корректно писать "не сделал". Это восклицание построено по типу вопросительного предложения: а есть ли такая вещь, которую я бы не сделал?

Но это не все. По-моему , корректно не "что бы", а "чего бы". Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

> Нет ничего на земле, чего бы я не сделал для нее. [Галина Щербакова. Моление о Еве (2000)]
>
> ― Да есть ли что-нибудь, чего бы я не сделал для нашего Нестора! [Фазиль Искандер. Сандро из Чегема (Книга 1) (1989)]
>
> ― Чего бы я не сделал, чтобы доказать это! [И. А. Гончаров. Обрыв (1869)]
>
> Ну, чего бы я не сделал, чего бы не свершил для этакого благополучия!.. [А. В. Сухово-Кобылин. Свадьба Кречинского (1855)]
>
> ― Опять скажу, не знаю, чего бы я не сделал для него и для тебя, ― отвечал Андрюша голосом живого соучастия. [И. И. Лажечников. Басурман (1838)]

А слов "что бы я не сделал" в Нацкорпусе нет.

Comment: Оставлю здесь цитату А.Островского: *"И нет того в мире, как бог свят, что б я не сделал, чтобы хоть малость заслужить любовь вашу..."* Подобное ещё попадается, но редко. Всё же, наверное, здесь стилистика хромает, не более того.

Answer (score -2):

Усилительная частица "ни".
"На какие только ухищрения ни пускается человек, чтобы не пропасть". В смысле: на что пускается человек, чтобы не пропасть.

А в предложении про дождь - ошибка.
Варианты:
Что бы я ни сделал - дождь не идёт.
На всё готов, чтобы дождь пошёл.

С частицей "не":
Чтобы я не сделал ошибку, на сайте "Русский язык" размещена справочная информация.
На что не пускается человек, так это на долгий путь к Марсу.

Здесь "не" отрицание действия и намерений.

Comment: Много примеров и рассуждений, а где ответ?  Запишите правильный вариант заданного предложения и объясните выбор частицы НЕ (отрицание) или НИ (усиление)..